# Objective-C passing parameters in void method

Tags: objective-c

How would I go about passing parameters when calling a void method? I understand that you can do something like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [self callMethod];
}

-(void)callMethod {
     //stuff here
}
```

But how would I pass a parameter, such as an `NSString`, to the `callMethod` method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example with an integer parameter.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [self callMethodWithCount:10];
}

-(void)callMethodWithCount:(NSInteger)count {
     //stuff here
}
```

In objective-c the parameters are included within the method name. You can add multiple parameters like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [self callMethodWithCount:10 animated:YES];
}

-(void)callMethodWithCount:(NSInteger)count animated:(BOOL)animate{
     //stuff here
}
```

It seems you may be misunderstanding what the void in the beginning of the method means. It's the return value. For a void method, nothing is returned from calling the method. If you wanted to return a value from your method you would do it like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    int myInt = [self callMethodWithCount:10 animated:YES];
}

-(int)callMethodWithCount:(NSInteger)count animated:(BOOL)animate{
     return 10;
}
```

You define your method to return an int (in this example it always returns 10.) Then you can set an integer to the value returned by calling the method.

Comment: I am a little confused what is question about? Question is titled "passing parameters in **void** method" but this answer is about "passing parameters in method".

Comment: My question was most likely phrase inappropriately. This is indeed the solution that I am looking for. What is the difference between a "void method" and just a "method"? I am relatively new to iOS development and am unfamiliar with terminology.

Comment: methods can return different types such as int or BOOL. a void method just returns nothing

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)callMethod:(NSString *)string 
{

}
```

Where `string` is your `parameter` so you would call

```
NSString *myString = @"your string here......";
[self callMethod:myString];
```